# refering to a variable within a repeat loop within a function

Tags: r

I'm using a repeat loop to remove duplicates in a data frame by adding 1 to each duplicated value. Like this:

```
library(Biobase)
    c <- data.frame(col_a = c(1,2,3,3,3,3,4), other_col = c(4,1,2,3,3,3,3))
        repeat{
          c$col_a[duplicated(c$col_a)] <- c$col_a[duplicated(c$col_a)] + 1
          if (length(c$col_a[!isUnique(c$col_a)]) == 0) break
        }
```

I was wondering why this function (where a column name is a variable) doesn't work:

```
   library(Biobase)
    f <- function(a){
          c <- data.frame(col_a = c(1,2,3,3,3,3,4), other_col = c(4,1,2,3,3,3,3))
          repeat{
          c$a[duplicated(c$a)] <- c$a[duplicated(c$a)] + 1
          if (length(c$a[!isUnique(c$a)]) == 0) break
          }
          return(c)
        }
        my_output <- f(col_a)
```

It's likely something trivial, but I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: In your function `f()` the object `a` is a character. There is a difference between a object name and a character value. If `a` is a character value you can not use `c$a` to access the column; you have to use `c[, a]` or `c[[a]]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your syntax is wrong:  `c$a` means column `"a"`, not the column whose name is in the variable `a`.  To get the latter, use `c[[a]]` or `c[, a]`.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was simple :)